The estimate of $L^p$ norm via duality argument.
Let $1<p<\infty$, $q$ be the conjugate of $p$, $E$ be a dense subset of $L^q(\mathbb R^n)$, $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb C$ be a measurable function.
Then, suppose the claim below holds :

There exists $C>0$ s.t. for all $g\in E$, we have $$\left|\int_{\mathbb R^n}fg\right|\leqq C\|g\|_q.$$

Then, why can we conclude that $f\in L^p(\mathbb R^n)$ and $\|f\|_p\leqq C$ ?
Probably, the outline is as follows :
By the estimate above, the mapping $T_f:E\to\mathbb C$, $g\mapsto \int_{\mathbb R^n}fg$ is bounded linear functional. Since $E$ is dense in $L^q$, there is unique mapping $\tilde{T_f}:L^q\to \mathbb C$ s.t. $\tilde{T_f}=T_f$ on $E$ and $|\tilde {T_f}(g)|\leqq C\|g\|_q$ for $g\in L^q.$ And we have $$\|\tilde{T_f}\|=\sup\left\{\frac{|\tilde{T_f}(g)|}{\|g\|_q} \ ; \ g\in L^q, g\neq 0\right\}\leqq C.$$
From this, can we comclude $f\in L^p$ and $\|f\|_p\leqq C$ ?
Edit
For the moment, I want to prove the case $E=\mathcal S$ (Schwartz class.)

Interesting question.

I guess it boils down to: If $w$ is measurable and $\int w g = 0$ for all $g \in E$, then is $w $ integrable?

Do you want to make use of the Riesz representation theorem to prove the claim or do you want to know how to conclude the result from what you have shown so far?

If possible, I want to prove without Riesz, but using Riesz is also O.K. In addition, for the moment I want to prove the case $E=\mathcal S$ (Schwartz class.) @DeanMiller

This is still an interesting question in general (not just for Schwartz), which I believe is tantamount to my comment above.

You can prove it for $E = C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$. Then the result follows as $C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n}) \subseteq \mathcal{S}$. By assumption,
\begin{equation}
\left| \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} f \tau \, d\mu \right| \leq C \|\tau\|_{L^{q}(\mathbb{R}^{n})} \tag{1}
\end{equation}
holds for all $\tau \in C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$.
Let $K\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be compact. Choose $\tau \in C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ with $\tau \geq 0$ such that $\tau\vert_{K} = \mathbb{1}_{K}$. Since $|\mathbb{1}_{K} f | \leq |f\tau |$ and $f\tau \in L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, one has $\mathbb{1}_{K}f\in L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$. Hence $f\in L^{1}_{{\rm loc}}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$.
Define $T:C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n}) \to \mathbb{C}$ by $T(\tau ) := \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}} f \tau \, d\mu$. By (1), $T$ is a bounded linear functional on $(C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n}), \|\cdot\|_{L^{q}})$ with $\|T\| \leq C$. Since $C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ is dense in $L^{q}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, $T$ has a unique extension $\widetilde{T}$ to a bounded linear functional on $L^{q}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ with $\|\widetilde{T} \| = \|T\|$.
By the Riesz representation theorem, there is some $\widetilde{f} \in L^{p}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ with $\|\widetilde{f} \|_{L^{p}(\mathbb{R}^{n})} = \|\widetilde{T}\|$ such that
\begin{equation}
\widetilde{T}(g) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} \widetilde{f} g \, d\mu
\end{equation}
for all $g\in L^{q}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$. In particular,
\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} f \tau \, d\mu = T(\tau ) = \widetilde{T}(\tau ) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} \widetilde{f} \tau \, d\mu
\end{equation}
holds for all $\tau \in C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$. Consequently, one has
\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} (f - \widetilde{f}) \tau \, d\mu = 0 \tag{2}
\end{equation}
for all $\tau \in C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$.
Since $f\in L^{1}_{{\rm loc}}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, $\widetilde{f} \in L^{p}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ and $L^{p}(\mathbb{R}^{n}) \subseteq L^{1}_{{\rm loc}}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, it follows that $f - \widetilde{f} \in L^{1}_{{\rm loc}}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$. By (2), it follows that $f - \widetilde{f} = 0$ almost everywhere. Hence $f\in L^{p}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ and $\|f\|_{L^{p}(\mathbb{R}^{n})} = \|T\| \leq C$ as desired.

What I have is not $\sup_g |\int fg|<\infty$ but $\sup_{g} |\tilde T_f(g)|<\infty$, thus I think we cannot use the theorem.  We have $\tilde T_f(g)=T_f(g)=\int fg$ only for $g\in E.$

That is a good point. I missed the distinction between those conditions. I have revised the answer to match up with that assumption. Apologies for the confusion regarding the previous answer.
